# Getting the total sum in simple cash register script

Tags: python

I just started learning Python and I would really appreciate some advice on this.

When I try to save the last total in the 'total_price' list, it doesn't save.
What am I doing wrong?

Also, are there any better ways to write this?
Thank you

```
price_list = {'gold': 10,
              'red': 20,
              'brown': 30
              }

vol_list = {'gold': 0.1,
            'red': 0.2,
            'brown': 0.3
            }

cl_list = {'gold': 100,
           'red': 200,
           'brown': 300
           }


while True:
    print("What do you want to buy?")
    choice = input("Choices: gold, red or brown > ")

    amount = int(input("How many do you want? >"))

    price = price_list[choice] * amount
    vol = (cl_list[choice] * amount) * vol_list[choice]

    total_price = []
    total_vol = []

    total_price.append(price)
    total_vol.append(vol)

    print_price = sum(total_price[:])
    print_vol = sum(total_vol[:])

    print("-" * 10)
    print("Your total is now: ", print_price)
    print("Your total vol is now: ", print_vol)
    print("-" * 10)

    cont = input("Do you want to continue shopping [Y/n]?> ")
if cont == "n" or cont == "no":
    print("#" * 10)
    print("#" * 10)
    print("Your total is: ", print_price)
    print("Your total vol is: ", print_vol)
    print("#" * 10)
    print("#" * 10)
    break
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are Initializing your arrays in your while loop, so on every new iteration the old `total_price` gets overwritten.

Initialize your arrays before you loop

```
total_price = []
total_vol = []


while True:
...
```